# Link to mongo.so 1.4 php driver compiled with php 5.4

Tags: php, mongodb

Can anyone point me to a site where i can download the Mongo DB v1.4 precompiled PHP Driver? I am running XAMPP and for the life of me can't compile the source with anything but PHP 5.3(version of php that came with my mac OS) is there anyone that has the precompiled v1.4 mongo.so file that has been compiled with PHP 5.4 that can share it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "pecl" tool that came with your XAMPP installation.

I believe it is installed into /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl .

So, you'll have to run:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo
```

To install the driver.

You'll then have to edit the XAMPP php.ini file, which I believe is /Applications/XAMPP/etc/php.ini (you should confirm with your phpinfo() output).